# CORS violation by Aura component

Tags: aura, iframe, cors

friends.

I have some simple aura components that renders a credit card payment form in an `iframe`.
This component works perfectly fine in production but browser fails with same-origin policy error in sandbox org. There is no entry with allowed CORS origin containing the origin of the `iframe source`.

Adding the source to CORS allowed list of sandbox organization does not solve the issue, and in production the issue does not occur.

Below is the code. Maybe you can show me what is wrong and where?

```
\\ cmp
<aura:component controller="SafeChargePaymentController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" extensible="true">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="mode" type="String" default="Iframe"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showIframe" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="action" type="String" default="credit"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit1}"/>
    
           <lightning:card>
               <iframe id="link1" name="myframe2" style="width: -webkit-fill-available;" frameborder="0">
               </iframe>
           </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

\\ controller
({
    doInit1 : function(comp, e, hlpr) {
        let openInIframe = comp.get("v.mode") == 'Iframe';
        comp.set("v.showIframe", openInIframe);
        let action1 = comp.get("c.getOrderData");
        action1.setParams({"OrderId": comp.get("v.recordId"),
                         "Method": comp.get("v.action")});
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            
            let state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var res  = response.getReturnValue();
                if(!res.endpoint){
                    comp.set("v.showIframe", false);
                    return;
                }
               
                hlpr.setForm1(res.endpoint,res.attMapByOrder,res.frmMethod,openInIframe); 
                // debugger;       
            } else {
                console.log('Problem getting response, response state: ' + state);
            }
         });
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);
                     
    }
})

\\ helper
({
    setForm1 : function(path, attributesMapByOrder, method,inIframe) {
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        
        let form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);
        let trgt = inIframe ? "myframe2" : "_blank"
        form.setAttribute("target", trgt); //myframe "_blank"
        
        console.log(`method ${method}`);
        console.log(`action ${path}`);
        console.log(`trgt ${trgt}`);
        let i=0;
            
        for(;i<Object.keys(attributesMapByOrder).length;i++) {
            let mapEntry = attributesMapByOrder[i];
            let key = mapEntry.key;
            let val = mapEntry.val;
            if(key.includes('quantity')){
                val = Number(val);
            }
            if(key == 'encoding'){
                key = 'encoding1';
            }
            let hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", val);
            fragment.appendChild(hiddenField);
            if(key == 'encoding1') {
                for ( var attrIndex = 0;  attrIndex < hiddenField.attributes.length; attrIndex++){
                    if (hiddenField.attributes[attrIndex].name == 'name') {
                        hiddenField.attributes[attrIndex].value = 'encoding';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        form.appendChild(fragment);    
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
})
```

Comment: have you checked the CSP and remote site settings in production?

Comment: I did, there is no mention of origin there either.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am also experiencing this issue